# Paint area under line in Afreechart

Tags: android, jfreechart

Is it possible to paint the area (maybe even with a gradient) under a line chart in afreechart (version 0.0.4) for Android? I want a result similar to the area charts in Jfreechart.

/Markus

Comment: It depends. What plot are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I found the easiest way to do this is to use a XYDifferenceRenderer. You have to add a second timeseries with all values set to 0 or whatever this minimum value on the chart is i.e. the values have to be on the x-axis. The XYDifferenceRenderer will simply highlight the area between the lines.